# i have problem with my sony m10

Tags: sony, m10

i have problem with my sony m10, i recorded a live gig in outdoors rock festival, my problem is the sound i've recorded is very low ,
i used SP-CMC-8 mics and sp-spsb-11 battery box, sony m10 setting was line input, limiter off,low cut off, iow mics sensitive, manual rec, level 8, 24bit 96k

volume indicator was mostly 50 percent i don't know why it was happened, i needed over 80 percent volume gain ,should i connect SP-CMC-8 to mics input? sony m10 has two inputs -mics  input and line input- should i have connected the mics to mics input?  i need your advice please solve my problem,

Comment: yup, mic & line have massively different requirements. You should have used mic.

Answer (score 1):

The mic input is for your microphone, yes.

Microphones have very low output, and a Line input expects a much higher voltage, so you have a low recorded signal.

Unfortunately this means your signal to noise ratio is not going to be good, and while there are ways to improve the situation, you basically cannot get away from this. Amplifying the signal will also amplify the noise.

In future you need to use the correct input.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks those mics operate with 5V plugin power. You should have connected them to the mic input and selected Yes when asked if you want power. Then 8 would have been way too much gain.